# Rust dynamically link .so library

Tags: rust, shared-libraries, .so

I have the following scenario and goals:

- Implement a library in Rust that has to be shared by many binaries
- Keep the size of the binary as small as possible

As far as I know, a way to get it is:

- Compile the library with `crate-type = "dylib"`. This generates the desired .so library
- Use the crate [libloading](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/index.html) to dynamically access the library objects from within a binary.

I successfully implemented a very basic example and the size of the compiled files are small enough. Here's the code:

**lib.rs**

```
#[no_mangle]
pub fn minicall() -> u8 {
    3u8
}
```

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new("liblibtest.so").unwrap();
        let func: libloading::Symbol<unsafe extern fn() -> u32> = lib.get(b"minicall").unwrap();
        let r = func();
        println!("r = {r}");
    }
}
```

Now, I need to expand my example by adding types and method to the lib, for example:

**lib.rs**

```
pub struct User {
    username: String,
    email: String,
}

impl User {
    fn new(username: String, email: String) -> User {
        User {
            username,
            email
        }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn minicall() -> u8 {
    3u8
}
```

and then, use them in my binary:

**main.rs**

```
fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let lib = libloading::Library::new("liblibtest.so").unwrap();
        
        let func: libloading::Symbol<unsafe extern fn() -> u32> = lib.get(b"minicall").unwrap();
        let r = func();
        println!("r = {r}");

        let user = ????  <----------------------
    }
}
```

How can I get access to types and methods in the library?
Please note that evereything is in Rust, no C is involved.

Comment: In general I would wrap functions in rust that you want to call with #[no_mangle] functions.

Comment: You can also depend on rust .so libraries with the dynamic linker deps as opposed to with libloading, and this way you don't have to worry about mangling.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to access rust symbols from rust with libloading? It will help with what strategy is most appropriate

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the final goal is to implement a library for modbus communication, so there will be a set of type (for example ModbusRequest) used by executable programs, for example a modbus client and a server

Comment: can you provide more details about dynamic linker deps? (your second comment)